# How to troubleshoot system freezing?

Tags: 10.10

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What should I do when Ubuntu freezes?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4408/what-should-i-do-when-ubuntu-freezes)

I have a problem with my Ubuntu 10.10 system which regularly freezes and can then only be switched off via the mains switch. When I try to re-start the system I need to try repeatedly before it will log in.

How can I trace the reason for this and correct it?

Comment: See also [What should I do when Ubuntu freezes?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/4408/what-should-i-do-when-ubuntu-freezes) - though that's not a duplicate because it doesn't tell you how to troubleshoot the causes.

Comment: What graphics card/chip do you run?

    lspci | grep VGA

Comment: I don't know - how can I obtain this information?

Answer (score 1):

Just saw a link about something similar: [Ubuntu Wiki Troubleshooting X freezes, hangs, and lockups](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Troubleshooting/Freeze). It may or may not be your problem, but that's a starting point.

Comment: @Brian Buck What solved it? How did you troubleshoot? Write your own answer and accept it if you need to.

Answer (score 0):

Open the log viewer from system->administration and look* for dmesg (reports kernel, network, boot and some overall info;eg will show if new HW is added) and xorg.log (the log for the graphic [server]). You'll then need the search for errors, most likely a graphic card/driver issue if you use Nvdia or Ati.

*if you don't see them directly, hit Ctrl+O and open the needed file, the file dialogue should be by default in /var/log.